# Exceptions in PHP - set_exception_handler output

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm starting to use `set_exception_handler` now. 
The first place I tested is the **try/catch** block for my `PDO` layer.

I forced an Exception with incorrect database credentials.
(this is before I applied the

```
<?php  

function log_exception($exception){
    print_r($exception);    
}

set_exception_handler("log_exception");

try { 
    $dbh = new PDO();
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION); 
    echo "connected!! \n";
} catch (PDOException $e) { 
    print_r($e); // let's see what it looks like
    throw new Exception($e); 
}
?>
```

You'll see `print_r` inside the **catch**, as well as in the **log_exception** function.

This is what gets displayed from **print_r($e)**:

```
PDOException Object
(
    [message:protected] => SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'localhost'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)
    [string:Exception:private] =>
    [code:protected] => 1045
    [file:protected] => /var/www/html/test.php
    [line:protected] => 35
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [file] => /var/www/html/test.php
                    [line] => 35
                    [function] => __construct
                    [class] => PDO
                    [type] => ->
                    [args] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=db_tests;charset=utf8
                            [1] => test
                            [2] => test
                        )

                )

        )

    [previous:Exception:private] =>
    [errorInfo] =>
)
```

And this is what gets displayed from **print_r($exception)** inside the **log_error()** function:

```
Exception Object
(
    [message:protected] => exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'localhost'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)' in /var/www/html/test.php:34
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/test.php(34): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=127.0...', 'test', 'test')
#1 {main}
    [string:Exception:private] =>
    [code:protected] => 0
    [file:protected] => /var/www/html/test.php
    [line:protected] => 34
    [trace:Exception:private] => Array
        (
        )

    [previous:Exception:private] =>
)
```

What are they different?
I am assuming that whatever Exception Object is passed into the **log_error()** function is going to be the same as what got generated within the **catch**.

Am I missing something?

...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be throwing the same exception if you want to forward it, not a new one:

```
throw $e;
```

Comment: I had a feeling is was something small and obvious.

Answer (score 2):

This is because they are two different Exceptions.

- http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdoexception.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/class.exception.php

As you can see here `PDOException` has some properties that `Exception` does not.
And what you are doing in the catch is throw a new `Exception`, with the previous Exception as the message.
The `Exception` constructor expects a string to be passed as message, and will then get the output of the `PDOExceptions` method `__toString`.
The other properties will be set according to where the last `Exception` was thrown.

As Cristik said, if you want to pass the `Exception` along you can just use `throw $e`. This will pass this `Exception` to the exception handler.

When you create a new `Exception` the line and file properties will be set according to where this `Exception` was instantiated. The trace will also be different. But all these will be kept intact if you just throw the one you caught.